# Upload photo with only publish_actions permission

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I've seen a few apps around that only asked for access for `users_photos` and `publish_actions` (not `publish_stream` or `photo_upload`). They are able to somehow upload photos, I think without even being approved for User Generated Photos (ie: Instagram).

How do these apps do this?

Comment: My guess would be that these apps do use user generated photos. It would be helpful to have a screenshot of an example post if you suspect this isn't the case.

Answer (score 0):

When you push an action (which you can do with the publish_actions permission), the object from the action can contain an image (through og:image). If so, an image is then shown on the timeline of the user and the newsfeed from his friends. However, the image is smaller as if you had posted it through a publish_stream or photo_upload).